# No such Gstreamer factory: v4l2src error in raspberry pi Processing

Tags: opencv, processing

[image: Screenshot of the error]

I'm using Raspberry PI with a webcam and Processing software.

It shows "No such Gstreamer factory: v4l2src" error, but the same code in Windows works fine.

Please help me to solve this problem. Thank you.

Comment: In the future, please try to post a [mcve] directly in your question instead of posting a screenshot of your code.

Comment: thank you for your advice, Sorry if you confuse about the question because I'm new to StackOverflow community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found a solution,
As in that site(http://www.raspberryconnect.com/raspbian-packages-list/item/69-raspbian-gnome), I installed GNOME packages.

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install GNOME
```

Answer (score 0):

Questions like these are best answered by entering your error message into Google. You'll find a ton of posts from people who have had the same problem in the past.

Here are a few examples I found in the first few results for googling "No such Gstreamer factory: v4l2src":

- [Movie / Capture not working](https://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/11321/movie-capture-not-working-linux-processing-2-2-1-3-0a5-3-0a10)
- [can not read any video or make it visible](https://github.com/processing/processing-video/issues/23)
- [How to use Processing 3 and the video capture library on Raspberry PI?](https://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/13485/how-to-use-processing-3-and-the-video-capture-library-on-raspberry-pi)
- [Ubuntu: IllegalArgumentException: No such Gstreamer factory: v4l2src](https://github.com/processing/processing-video/issues/52)

It sounds like you need to install some dependencies to get this to work. Or there are other libraries that work out of the box. But the moral of the story is: don't be afraid to Google your error!

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I already searched about the error in google since in a week. I tried all that links but didn't find any useful. finally today I found the answer.it's mentioned below.